# Copy-Item if newer with Get-ChildItem parameters and exclusions

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, copy-item

I have a script that will monitor a folder, and copy files that meet parameters to a separate location and rename. I have the `GCI` exclude files from the `$source` that already exist in the `$destination`, but would like for the exclusion to be skipped if the `$source` file has a newer timestamp. i.e. if a newer version of a file exists in the `$source`, copy it to the `$destination`, otherwise skip it.

What I currently have:

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    GCI -Path $output -Filter "*$($file.Files)*" -Include '*.jpg' -Exclude $alreadyMoved.Name -Recurse |
        Copy-Item -Destination $destination -PassThru |
        Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'PC_...','PC_620'} 
}
```

I'm not sure the most efficient way to do this, but I need it to operate smoothly and sort/filter in the correct order to make the `GCI` as fast as possible.

Comment: Have you considered using a WMI event sink instead. No need to do a full folder GCI at all then. It would fire whenever there is a new file and your code could then just compare the new file to whatever is in the destination folder.

Comment: If you want to periodically sync a directory tree I'd recommend using `robocopy`.

Comment: @EBGreen I am totally unfamiliar with WMI Events but a quick google search leads me to believe that may be the best way to go. Do you have any particular reading that may help me learn how to do that? What cmdlets do you recommend I use? 

Would this leave a running PowerShell window on the user's end? I planned on having the above run via task scheduler (through a vbs argument I have that makes PowerShell invisible) but if the WMI event allows for a clean user experience I'd be happy to try it.

Comment: See if this gets you going in the right direction: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b